# Caching search results in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, search

I have a DB with a user collection, a book collection, and a comment collection.

I would like to perform a site-wide search capability and for that reason I would like to create a new collection of indexed content for search entries.

The new collection I imagine will look like this:

```
var indexContent= mongoose.Schema({
    keyword:String //The keyword search
    rank: Number //a ranking I give the matched document
    refType: String //either "User", "Series", or "Episode"
    ref: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId //The id of the matched document,
    date: Date // date when this entry was created
})
```

I feel like this is ideal because, whenever a keyword exists in the collection I can quickly retrieve the results, and if the keyword was never searched before, I generate the results for the first time, then save it to serve to other people.

The problem is, considering the site has a very high rate of updates, how often should I dump my cached results?

Comment: We can't really answer this for you as it's entirely dependent upon the requirements of your users for up-to-date query results.

Comment: Is this a best-practice guideline?